# How to remove prefix/namespace from xml

Tags: html, xml, xslt

i have following xml file:

```
<q1:GeneralAgenda xmlns="http://schemas.gov.sk/form/Notify.GeneralAgenda/1.1">
  <q1:subject>text text text</q1:subject>
  <q1:text>lorem ipsum</q1:text>
</q1:GeneralAgenda>
```

and i created xsl file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ga="http://schemas.gov.sk/form/Notify.GeneralAgenda/1.1">


<xsl:template match="ga:GeneralAgenda">
  <html>
   <head>

    </head> 
  <body>

   <div id="main" class="layoutMain">
      <div class="layoutRow ui-tabs ui-widget-content">
         <div class="caption ui-widget-header">
            <div class="headercorrection">Všeobecná agenda - oznámenie</div>
         </div>

         <div><label class="labelVis">Predmet: </label>

           <span class="contentVis wordwrap">

             <xsl:value-of select="ga:subject"/>

           </span>

        </div>

         <div class="clear"> </div>
         <div><label class="labelVis">Text: </label>
           <span class="contentVis wordwrap">

            <xsl:value-of select="ga:text"/>

           </span>
         </div>
         <div class="clear"> </div>
      </div>
   </div>

  </body>

  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

problem is it doesn't work because of the "q1:" part in xml file, how do i correct this? I'm using java to generate hmtl file from xml file, it works fine when i remove q1 manually, i think there is a way to adjust xsl file but i just don't know how.

Comment: If that input is supposed to be namespace well-formed XML then it lacks a namespace declaration for the `q1` prefix used in e.g. `q1:GeneralAgenda`. So I don't think you will get that snippet by any XML parser an XSLT processor uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general rule is to:

- Remove explicit "user" namespaces from the XSLT script (but keep *xsl*
  namespace prefix).
- Specify `match` or `select` attributes using `*[local-name() = '...']`.

So you can use a script like below, a bit reworked version of your script.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
    doctype-system= "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[local-name() = 'GeneralAgenda']">
    <html>
      <head>
      </head> 
      <body>
        <div id="main" class="layoutMain">
          <div class="layoutRow ui-tabs ui-widget-content">
            <div class="caption ui-widget-header">
              <div class="headercorrection">Všeobecná agenda - oznámenie</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label class="labelVis">Predmet: </label>
              <span class="contentVis wordwrap">
                <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name() = 'subject']"/>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"> </div>
            <div>
              <label class="labelVis">Text: </label>
              <span class="contentVis wordwrap">
                <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name() = 'text']"/>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"> </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For a working example see http://xsltransform.net/pNvs5w3/1

Note the source XML content in the example given above.
The `xmlns` declaration must include `:q1` prefix.

```
<q1:GeneralAgenda xmlns:q1="urn:dummy_q1">
```

Failing to do so causes that your source XML is not properly formatted
and even such "basic" implementation as *Xalan* fails.